# Operations by "for" function on ArrayList and Exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, exception, arraylist, netbeans

I have a problem with my code. I wrote a simple operations on ArrayLists and have an Exception.
Below is my code:

```
for (int i=0;i<Core.Config.amountInclu;i++) {
            Random r = new Random();
            x = r.nextInt(this.tabSizeX);
            y = r.nextInt(this.tabSizeY);
                            Pkt nowy = new Pkt(x,y);
                            while(newPkt.contains(nowy) || onBoundary(x,y)==false){

                                x = r.nextInt(this.tabSizeX);
                                y = r.nextInt(this.tabSizeY);
                            }
                            for(int j = 0; j<Core.Config.sizeInclu;j++){
                                for(int k = 0; k<Core.Config.sizeInclu;j++){
                                    if((x+j)<tabSizeX && (y+k)<tabSizeY){
                                        this.P[x+j][y+k].set_black();
                                        newPkt.add(nowy);
                                    }
                                }

                            }

        }
```

After run this code I have an exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -2147483648
at growth_1.Plansza.addInclusion(Plansza.java:661)
at growth_1.Display$18.mouseClicked(Display.java:399)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6542)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4544)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

The algorithm is very simple, we draw a point on JPanel (x,y) and checking if it was already used and if it is on boundary of bigger cell. If yes, we must draw another point.
And then we must set color black to point and neighbouring points.
I thought that I checked all conditions to protect points be out of bounds.

I will be very grateful, if you give me an advice.

Answer (score 1):

I can only suppose, that problem is because of in the statement

```
for(int k = 0; k<Core.Config.sizeInclu;j++)...
```

You have copy-paste error: j++ instead of k++